# How do I fix "retCode":170003 error using ccxt and bybit?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, ccxt, bybit, python-bybit

I am trying to build a bot that buys btc/usdt for 50 usdt on bybit using ccxt and python. I also have a stoploss at 0.33% and a take profit at 0.45%. But when I try to run it, I get this message:

```
"Market order failed with error: bybit {"retCode":170003,"retMsg":"An unknown parameter was sent.","result":{},"retExtInfo":{},"time":1698675395747}"
```

This is my code:

```
# Define your Bybit API credentials
api_key = '<Here is my api key>'
api_secret = '<Here is my screct api key>'

# Initialize the Bybit exchange
exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'apiKey': api_key,
    'secret': api_secret,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

# Set the option to allow market buy orders without price
exchange.options["createMarketBuyOrderRequiresPrice"] = False

# Define trading parameters
symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
cost_in_usdt = 50  # The cost of the buy order in USDT
entry_price = None  # Market order, so entry price is not specified
stop_loss_percent = 0.0033  # 0.33% stop loss as a float (0.33% = 0.0033)
take_profit = 0.0045  # 0.45% take profit as a float (0.45% = 0.0045)

# Get the current market price
ticker = exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)
market_price = ticker['last']

# Calculate the quantity of BTC to buy
quantity = cost_in_usdt / market_price

# Place a market order to buy BTC/USDT
try:
    market_order = exchange.create_order(
        symbol,
        'market',
        'buy',
        quantity
    )
    print(f"Market order to buy {quantity} BTC placed at market price.")
    
    # Update the entry price based on the market order response
    entry_price = market_order['price']
    
    # Calculate stop loss and take profit prices
    stop_loss_price = entry_price * (1 - stop_loss_percent)
    take_profit_price = entry_price * (1 + take_profit)
    
    # Place a stop market sell order (stop loss)
    stop_loss_order = exchange.create_order(
    symbol,
    'limit',
    'sell',
    quantity,
    stop_loss_price,
        {'stopPrice': stop_loss_price}
    )

    
    # Place a take profit market sell order
    take_profit_order = exchange.create_order(
        symbol,
        'market',
        'sell',
        quantity
    )
    
    print(f"Stop loss order placed at {stop_loss_price}.")
    print(f"Take profit order placed at {take_profit_price}.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Market order failed with error: {str(e)}")`
```

I've tried fix it with some other lines of code. I tried to add different parameters, or switch to a limit/market order. But that all can't seem it fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error code (170003) using pybit module when submitting a limit order with stop loss (I did not use take profit).

What helped me was to provide two additional stoploss arguments: `slTriggerBy="LastPrice"` and `slOrderType="Market"` as described in Bybit V5 API documentation.